# How to group drivable areas in YOLOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, grouping

On YOLOP, I can detect the lanes and drivable areas without problem. The data comes out of a torch model and being stored as a 2D numpy array such as like that:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

This 2D numpy array stores only 0's and 1's corresponding to not-a-drivable-area and drivable-area. And if I plot the output with pyplot, this is [what we have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyzIJ.png)

My question kicks in here. I have to separate these 3 different lanes of drivable areas into separate groups (arrays) so I can use the required drivable area **only**. [For example...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ancRJ.png)

So when I decide to show only the `drivableLane[0]`, i should get an output like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOA4u.png)

At first I've tried to iterate the whole 2D array one by one and store the drivable-area coordinates but it was a bad idea due to this operation being too slow. I've also came up with the DBSCAN and BIRCH clustering algorithms but at the end, i screwed.

I would appreciate to hear an idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example image you provided:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyzIJ.png'
response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img = np.array(img)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Where we have RGB(A) values of the image represented as a `numpy` matrix:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(img[300:800, 300:600, :3])
ax.set_title('Zoom in')
ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(img[400:600, 300:600, :3])
ax.set_title('Zoom in more')
ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(img[450:550, 400:500, :3])
for r in range(10, img[450:550, 400:500, :3].shape[0] - 20, 20):
    for c in range(10, img[450:550, 400:500, :3].shape[1], 20):
        ax.text(r, c, str(np.round(np.mean(img[r, c, :]), decimals=0)))
ax.set_title('Perfect... now show the values')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Which you said is already `0`'s and `1`'s (which is great! even easier), we can make those matrices of `1`'s according to the `row`, `col`umn indices of drivable areas that don't overlap.

Let's visualize it here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def draw_shape(ax, x, y, size, layers, layer_colors, layer_alpha, **kwargs):
    for layer in range(layers):
        for line in range(size + 1):
            ax.plot(np.ones(10)*x + line + layer, np.linspace(y + layer, y + size + layer, 10), color=[0, 0, 0], **kwargs)
            ax.plot(np.linspace(y + layer, y + size + layer, 10), np.ones(10)*x + line + layer, color=[0, 0, 0], **kwargs)
            if line < size:
                for row in range(size):
                    ax.text(x + line + layer + (size / 2.5) - 1.0, y + layer + (size / 2) - 1.0 + row, '[' + str(row + x) + ', ' + str(line) + ']')
        ax.fill_between(range(layer, size + layer + 1), x + layer, x + size + layer, color=layer_colors[layer], alpha=layer_alpha)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
draw_shape(ax, 0, 0, 3, 1, [[1, 1, 1]], 1.0, lw=2.5, ls='-')
draw_shape(ax, 2.0, 2.0, 3, 1, [[1, 1, 1]], 1.0, lw=2.5, ls='-')
ax.axis('off')
ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
draw_shape(ax, 0, 0, 3, 1, [[1, 1, 1]], 1.0, lw=2.5, ls='-')
draw_shape(ax, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 1, [[1, 1, 1]], 1.0, lw=2.5, ls='-')
ax.axis('off')
ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
draw_shape(ax, 0, 0, 3, 1, [[1, 1, 1]], 1.0, lw=2.5, ls='-')
draw_shape(ax, 3.1, 3.1, 3, 1, [[1, 1, 1]], 1.0, lw=2.5, ls='-')
ax.axis('off')
plt.show
```

[image]

We can discriminate between the boundaries by checking if neighboring locations in the image are also drivable areas (`1`'s):

```
for row in range(img.shape[0]):
    for col in range(img.shape[1]):
        if img[row, col] == 1.0:
            # here is where the rules go:
            # example: if there's at least one neighboring '1.0':
            if any([img[max(0, row - 1), col], img[row, max(0, col - 1)], img[max(0, row - 1), max(0, col - 1)], img[min(img.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), col], img[row, min(img.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)], img[min(img.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), min(img.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)]]):
                ...
```

And we can also discriminate the border of the drivable areas (`1`'s) in the image (or if you want to have the matrix for the "background" or non-drivable areas in the image):

```
for row in range(img.shape[0]):
    for col in range(img.shape[1]):
        if img[row, col] == 1.0:
            # here is where the rules go:
            # example: if there's at least one neighboring '1.0':
            if any([img[max(0, row - 1), col], img[row, max(0, col - 1)], img[max(0, row - 1), max(0, col - 1)], img[min(img.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), col], img[row, min(img.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)], img[min(img.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), min(img.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)]]):
                ...
        else:
            # get borders:
            if any([img[max(0, row - 1), col], img[row, max(0, col - 1)], img[max(0, row - 1), max(0, col - 1)], img[min(img.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), col], img[row, min(img.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)], img[min(img.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), min(img.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)]]):
                ...
            # get background:
            else:
                ...
```

For example, if we have `a` matrix of `0`'s and fill the top left corner with `1`'s:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((4, 4))
a[:2, :2] = 1.0
```

`print(a)`:

```
[[1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

We can discriminate the locations of `1`'s and their neighbors (the `0`'s):

```
for row in range(a.shape[0]):
    for col in range(a.shape[1]):
        if a[row, col] == 1.0:
            if any([a[max(0, row - 1), col], a[row, max(0, col - 1)], a[max(0, row - 1), max(0, col - 1)], a[min(a.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), col], a[row, min(a.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)], a[min(a.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), min(a.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)]]):
                print('equals 1:', str(row), str(col))
        else:
            if any([a[max(0, row - 1), col], a[row, max(0, col - 1)], a[max(0, row - 1), max(0, col - 1)], a[min(a.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), col], a[row, min(a.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)], a[min(a.shape[0] - 1, row + 1), min(a.shape[1] - 1, col + 1)]]):
                print('Neighbor:', str(row), str(col))
            else:
                print('Background:', str(row), str(col))
```

Getting the locations `[row`, `col`umn`]` of this "square object" (of `1`'s) from `a` matrix (of `0`'s) or "image" array:

```
equals 1: 0 0
equals 1: 0 1
Neighbor: 0 2
Background: 0 3
equals 1: 1 0
equals 1: 1 1
Neighbor: 1 2
Background: 1 3
Neighbor: 2 0
Neighbor: 2 1
Neighbor: 2 2
Background: 2 3
Background: 3 0
Background: 3 1
Background: 3 2
Background: 3 3
```

Now if `a` has multiple drivable areas:

```
a = np.zeros((10, 20))
a[:, 2:4] = 1.0
a[:, -4:-2] = 1.0
a[:2, 4] = 1.0
a[:3, -5] = 1.0
```

which looks like `print(a)`:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

or `plt.imshow(a)`:

[image]

and we want to partition those `1`'s into separate `list`s (this example will be easier to convey using nested `list`s inside a `dict`ionary instead of matrices), we can make `some_lists_in_dict` which will contain each drivable area (numbered in order represented as `keys`) and its `values` as `row`, `col`umn `list`s; as a `dict`ionary, each "new" drivable area will be inserted as a new `list` in the order in which it is discriminated, and `row`, `col`umn values will be compared with all drivable areas (`append`ed to pre-existing `list`s if it `is_part_of` that drivable area, or made into a new `list` for a new drivable area):

```
some_lists_in_dict = {'0': []}

def is_part_of(x, y, some_list, neighbors=[-1, 0, 1]):
    for row in neighbors:
        for col in neighbors:
            if [x + row, y + col] in some_list:
                    return True
    return False

for row in range(a.shape[0]):
    for col in range(a.shape[1]):
        if a[row, col] == 1.0:
            if len(some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()) - 1)]):
                if any([is_part_of(row, col, some_lists_in_dict[key]) for key in some_lists_in_dict.keys()]):
                    some_lists_in_dict[[[key for key in some_lists_in_dict.keys() if is_part_of(row, col, some_lists_in_dict[key])]][0][0]].append([row, col])
                else:
                    some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()))] = []
                    some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()) - 1)].append([row, col])
            else:
                some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()) - 1)].append([row, col])
```

and `print(some_lists_in_dict)` shows us that it correctly discriminates the two drivable areas:

```
{'0': [[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2], [4, 3], [5, 2], [5, 3], [6, 2], [6, 3], [7, 2], [7, 3], [8, 2], [8, 3], [9, 2], [9, 3]], '1': [[0, 15], [0, 16], [0, 17], [1, 15], [1, 16], [1, 17], [2, 15], [2, 16], [2, 17], [3, 16], [3, 17], [4, 16], [4, 17], [5, 16], [5, 17], [6, 16], [6, 17], [7, 16], [7, 17], [8, 16], [8, 17], [9, 16], [9, 17]]}
```

### Edge Cases

What about edge cases where `a` matrix has some "awkwardly" shaped drivable areas? We can see in this example where `is_part_of` will incorrectly discriminate a separate drivable area when iterating `col`umns and `row` is `2`; the white dashed lines represent iterating `col`umns, and the red boxes represent the `neighbors` that the `is_part_of` function relies on:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((10, 20))
a[3:-1, 4] = 1.0
a[1, -3:-2] = 1.0
a[4:7, 7:10] = 1.0
a[4, 7:9] = 0.0
a[-5:-1, 1:4] = 1.0
a[-8:-2, -7:-4] = 1.0
a[-2, -10:-3] = 1.0
a[-8, -7:-3] = 1.0
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax.plot(range(18), np.ones(18), ls='--', lw=1.5, color=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], zorder=2)
for y in range(3):
    ax.plot(range(16, 19), np.ones(3)*y, ls='--', lw=1.0, color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], zorder=1)
    ax.plot(np.ones(3)*(16 + y), range(0, 3), ls='--', lw=1.0, color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], zorder=1)
ax.imshow(a, zorder=0)
ax.set_title('"for col in..." when row is 1')
ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
ax.plot(range(18), np.ones(18), ls='--', lw=1.5, color=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], zorder=2)
ax.plot(range(14), np.ones(14)*2, ls='--', lw=1.5, color=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], zorder=2)
for y in range(3):
    ax.plot(range(16, 19), np.ones(3)*y, ls='--', lw=1.0, color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], zorder=1)
    ax.plot(np.ones(3)*(16 + y), range(0, 3), ls='--', lw=1.0, color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], zorder=1)
    ax.plot(range(12, 15), np.ones(3)*(y + 1), ls='--', lw=1.0, color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], zorder=1)
    ax.plot(np.ones(3)*(12 + y), range(1, 4), ls='--', lw=1.0, color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], zorder=1)
ax.imshow(a, zorder=0)
ax.set_title('"for col in..." when row is 2 and is_part_of() fails')
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can `refactor` `some_lists_in_dict`; this function is similar to the `is_part_of` function, but it compares one drivable area `row` `col`umn `list` with every other drivable area `list`, and instead of `return`ing `True` it `return`s `some_new_lists_in_dict` after combining two drivable areas--`some_lists_in_dict[key]` `append`s `some_lists_in_dict[_key]` and `some_lists_in_dict[_key]` is `del`eted:

```
def refactor(some_lists_in_dict, some_new_lists_in_dict=some_lists_in_dict.copy(), neighbors=[-1, 0, 1]):
    for key in some_lists_in_dict.keys(): # list being compared; some_lists_in_dict[key] or xy;
        for _key in list(some_lists_in_dict.keys())[int(key) + 1:]: # comparison list(s); some_lists_in_dict[_key];
            if any([[xy[0] + row, xy[1] + col] in some_lists_in_dict[_key] for xy in some_lists_in_dict[key] for row in neighbors for col in neighbors]):
                some_lists_in_dict[key] += some_lists_in_dict[_key]
                del some_new_lists_in_dict[_key]
                new_keys = int(key)
                for old_keys in range(int(_key) + 1, len(some_lists_in_dict.keys())):
                    del some_new_lists_in_dict[str(old_keys)]
                    new_keys += 1
                    some_new_lists_in_dict[str(new_keys)] = some_lists_in_dict[str(old_keys)]
                return some_new_lists_in_dict
```

Since we may not know how many drivable areas there are beforehand, we can `@keep_refactoring` by using a `while` `loop` `decorator` that calls the `refactor` function until it can't `refactor` `some_lists_in_dict` any further:

```
def keep_refactoring(some_function):
    def wrapper(some_lists_in_dict, some_new_lists_in_dict=some_lists_in_dict.copy()):
        while some_lists_in_dict is not None:
            some_lists_in_dict = some_function(some_new_lists_in_dict)
            some_new_lists_in_dict = some_lists_in_dict if some_lists_in_dict is not None else some_new_lists_in_dict
        return some_new_lists_in_dict
    return wrapper

@keep_refactoring
def refactor(some_lists_in_dict, some_new_lists_in_dict=some_lists_in_dict.copy(), neighbors=[-1, 0, 1]):
    for key in some_lists_in_dict.keys(): # list being compared; some_lists_in_dict[key] or xy;
        for _key in list(some_lists_in_dict.keys())[int(key) + 1:]: # comparison list(s); some_lists_in_dict[_key];
            if any([[xy[0] + row, xy[1] + col] in some_lists_in_dict[_key] for xy in some_lists_in_dict[key] for row in neighbors for col in neighbors]):
                some_lists_in_dict[key] += some_lists_in_dict[_key]
                del some_new_lists_in_dict[_key]
                new_keys = int(key)
                for old_keys in range(int(_key) + 1, len(some_lists_in_dict.keys())):
                    del some_new_lists_in_dict[str(old_keys)]
                    new_keys += 1
                    some_new_lists_in_dict[str(new_keys)] = some_lists_in_dict[str(old_keys)]
                return some_new_lists_in_dict
```

We can incorporate `is_part_of` and `refactor` functions together, or we can just `refactor` `some_lists_in_dict` afterwards:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((10, 20))
a[3:-1, 4] = 1.0
a[1, -3:-2] = 1.0
a[4:7, 7:10] = 1.0
a[4, 7:9] = 0.0
a[-5:-1, 1:4] = 1.0
a[-8:-2, -7:-4] = 1.0
a[-2, -10:-3] = 1.0
a[-8, -7:-3] = 1.0

some_lists_in_dict = {'0': []}

def is_part_of(x, y, some_list, neighbors=[-1, 0, 1]):
    for row in neighbors:
        for col in neighbors:
            if [x + row, y + col] in some_list:
                    return True
    return False

for row in range(a.shape[0]):
    for col in range(a.shape[1]):
        if a[row, col] == 1.0:
            if len(some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()) - 1)]):
                if any([is_part_of(row, col, some_lists_in_dict[key]) for key in some_lists_in_dict.keys()]):
                    some_lists_in_dict[[[key for key in some_lists_in_dict.keys() if is_part_of(row, col, some_lists_in_dict[key])]][0][0]].append([row, col])
                else:
                    some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()))] = []
                    some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()) - 1)].append([row, col])
            else:
                some_lists_in_dict[str(len(some_lists_in_dict.keys()) - 1)].append([row, col])

def keep_refactoring(some_function):
    def wrapper(some_lists_in_dict, some_new_lists_in_dict=some_lists_in_dict.copy()):
        while some_lists_in_dict is not None:
            some_lists_in_dict = some_function(some_new_lists_in_dict)
            some_new_lists_in_dict = some_lists_in_dict if some_lists_in_dict is not None else some_new_lists_in_dict
        return some_new_lists_in_dict
    return wrapper

@keep_refactoring
def refactor(some_lists_in_dict, some_new_lists_in_dict=some_lists_in_dict.copy(), neighbors=[-1, 0, 1]):
    for key in some_lists_in_dict.keys(): # list being compared; some_lists_in_dict[key] or xy;
        for _key in list(some_lists_in_dict.keys())[int(key) + 1:]: # comparison list(s); some_lists_in_dict[_key];
            if any([[xy[0] + row, xy[1] + col] in some_lists_in_dict[_key] for xy in some_lists_in_dict[key] for row in neighbors for col in neighbors]):
                some_lists_in_dict[key] += some_lists_in_dict[_key]
                del some_new_lists_in_dict[_key]
                new_keys = int(key)
                for old_keys in range(int(_key) + 1, len(some_lists_in_dict.keys())):
                    del some_new_lists_in_dict[str(old_keys)]
                    new_keys += 1
                    some_new_lists_in_dict[str(new_keys)] = some_lists_in_dict[str(old_keys)]
                return some_new_lists_in_dict

some_lists_in_dict = refactor(some_lists_in_dict)
```

and `print(some_lists_in_dict)`:

```
{'0': [[1, 17], [2, 16], [3, 15], [4, 14], [4, 15], [5, 13], [5, 14], [5, 15], [6, 13], [6, 14], [6, 15], [7, 13], [7, 14], [7, 15], [8, 12], [8, 13], [8, 14], [8, 15], [8, 16], [2, 13], [2, 14], [2, 15], [3, 13], [3, 14], [4, 13], [8, 10], [8, 11]], '1': [[3, 4], [4, 4], [5, 3], [5, 4], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [7, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [8, 1], [8, 2], [8, 3], [8, 4], [5, 1], [5, 2], [6, 1]], '2': [[4, 9], [5, 8], [5, 9], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [5, 7]]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I implement the code into my project, detection and calculating the locations took about `Done. (9.288s)` . Considering that this project will be used for camera feed in real time, I think that it has to be a bit more faster.